Is it possible to use binding for 'value' parameter of a static query in Salesforce Einstein Analytics?
I am working on a requirement where I need to pass value from date widget to a toggle widget on selection of date from date widget.
Ex: User Selects 'Next year' then I want to take this output and pass on to my toggle widget which is built using static query.
Is this possible?
Tried using binding but no luck
